# Definition of Spin structure?

Tags: vector-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I've encountered the following definition of spin structure:

"Let $p:P\rightarrow B$ a principal $SO(p,q)$-bundle, a spin structure" (over the associated vector bundle with metric and orientation) is a $Spin(p,q)$-bundle $\widetilde{p}:\widetilde{P}\rightarrow B$ such that

(i)There's a bundle map $\widetilde{r}:\widetilde{P}\rightarrow P$ that's a double cover;

(ii)The following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spin(p,q)&\times & \widetilde{P}&\stackrel{right\hspace{3mm}tr.}{\longrightarrow} &\widetilde{P}\\
\downarrow{r} & &\downarrow{\widetilde{r}} && \downarrow{\widetilde{r}}\\
SO(p,q) & \times & P & \stackrel{right\hspace{3mm}tr.}{\longrightarrow} & P\\
\end{CD}$$
commutes".
Here r is the natural double cover of $SO(p,q)$.

My question is about that bracket sentence :"over the associated bundle with metric and orientation". What does that mean explicitly? It seems that we're implicitly considering another vector bundle...
I say that cause a spin structure over a pseudorienmanian manifold $M$ is said to be a Spin structure over the tangent bundle $TM$. What does that mean? How is the above definition linked with the tangent bundle of a manifold (that's a vector bundle)?
I mean, I can't see where does $TM$ enter in the game, I hope to have been clear enough.

EDIT: Can maybe cause $TM$ has an associated frame bundle $E_{GL}$ with fiber $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ which can have a reduction to $SO(p,q)$?

Comment: Yes, the existence of a metric and orientation on the vector bundle gives an explicit way to reduce the structure group from $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $SO(p,q)$.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. What sounds weird to me is how can I be sure that $E_{GL}=\bigcup U_{\alpha}\times GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})/\sim$ built as known is a principal bundle...I've already asked that question if you check my profile, but no-one answered yet. Thank you btw